# Why can't I publish my web site in VS2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, web-publishing

When I try to publish my ASP.Net MVC web site, I get the following page:
[image]

The lonely looking `Publish` button does nothing.

Any ideas how I fix this?

Comment: Can you please confirm the project type? Also, if this is an existing project, can you try moving all the files under Properties\PublishProfiles outside the project and try Publish again?

Comment: It's an ASP.Net MVC web application. I said that in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and it solved by changing csproj file:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
```

changed to

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="true" />
```

This only works of course if you're trying to update an older project to the newer VS2017 environment.